# blazor wasm inject IJSRuntime in program.cs Main

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, program-entry-point, webassembly

in Blazor Webassembly,
is it possible to inject IJSRuntime in program.cs, to Main method ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get it from the services container

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });


    var host = builder.Build();

    var jsRuntime = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>(); // get the service from the DI container
    // do something like get the culture - that's what the MS example for that does
    var cultureName = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Comment: is it possible/recommended to assign jsRuntime to a global static variable and access it when ever needed?